# Populate range of alpha-numeric values given start and end points

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, range, data-manipulation

There is a table of three columns and ~9,400 rows listing beginning and end values for alpha-numeric ranges of codes along with a third value assigned to the ranges.  It is desired to change the two columns of range endpoints into a single column of explicitly listed (1:1) values.  Can you think of a method to automate explicitly listing values within the ranges?

Current example row:
|---r1----|---r2----|ccs|
| 0106T | 0110T |  7  |

Desired output:
|--code-|ccs|
| 0106T |   7 |
| 0107T |   7 |
| 0108T |   7 |
| 0109T |   7 |
| 0110T |   7 |

This is stored in a MySQL database and Excel workbook, but any language or manor of manipulation is fine.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I was honestly stumped, which is why I asked the question.  I was thinking of an SQL cursor (*gasp*), but R3uK has a great solution below.  I am modifying it to get the specific results needed - split results into two columns, maintain leading zeroes, and handle different values (00305, A6047, 0023C, etc).  Will post solution when finished, thanks.

Comment: It's alright if you have got the solution. Make sure to accept the answer you find useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only with a "T" this will work and is a good base to your full macro :

```
Sub Alpha()
Dim WsS As Worksheet
Set WsS = Worksheets("Source")
Dim WsR As Worksheet
Set WsR = DeleteAndAddSheet("Results")

For i = 2 To WsS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For k = Val(WsS.Cells(i, 1)) To Val(WsS.Cells(i, 2))
        WsR.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = k & "T " & WsS.Cells(i, 3)
    Next k

Next i

End Sub
```

Useful function for Sheets :

```
Public Function DeleteAndAddSheet(ByVal SheetName As String) As Worksheet

For Each aShe In Sheets
    If aShe.Name <> SheetName Then
    Else
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        aShe.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next aShe

Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = SheetName

Set DeleteAndAddSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

End Function
```

Comment: Great place to start, thank you for your help!  Will post final solution when completed.

Comment: Glad I could help, I was in a hurry so I didn't finish, but to make it flexible (regarding the letter), you can use something like a `while` on `IsNumeric(mid(wss.cells(i,1),MovingStart,1))` and you will have the "address" of your first letter to use a `Right(wss.cells(i, 1),Len(wss.Cells(i,1))-MovingStart + or - 1)` to get the non numeric part. For the start with "0", you can simply add it in text or use Format().

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the solution provided by R3uK, there appears to be an error in the DeleteAndAddSheet function in the Set DeleteAndAddSheet statement.  The statement errors with a Subscript out of Range error.  not sure whether the expected result is the sheet number or not.
R3uK, can you clarify?
Thanks.

Comment: It's not the number it's directly the sheet created so that it can be Set as an object in further coding. Still it's strange that you have an error on that... Were you trying to affect result to a numerical value?  Or maybe change ThisWorkbook to ActiveWorkbook...

Comment: Look at the end of the line of the function, it's declared as a Worksheet, so the result must be a Worksheet ;)

Answer (score 0):

FYI this is some sample data and the final macro used.  I am not a programmer and have reached a "good enough" point.  Big thanks to R3uK for leading the way:

r1  |   r2  |   ccs 
0001T   |   0002T   |   52  
0003T   |   0003T   |   130 
0005T   |   0006T   |   59  
0007T   |   0007T   |   211 
0008T   |   0008T   |   93  
0009T   |   0009T   |   125 
00100   |   00104   |   232 
0010T   |   0010T   |   40  
00120   |   00126   |   232 
0012T   |   0013T   |   162 
00140   |   00148   |   232 
0014T   |   0014T   |   176 
17999   |   17999   |   175 
19000   |   19001   |   165 
19020   |   19020   |   175 
19030   |   19103   |   165 
C2018   |   C2018   |   243 
C2019   |   C2019   |   243 
C2020   |   C2020   |   243 
C2021   |   C2021   |   243 
C2022   |   C2022   |   243 
C2023   |   C2023   |   243

```
Public Function DeleteAndAddSheet(ByVal SheetName As String) As Worksheet

For Each aShe In Sheets
    If aShe.Name <> SheetName Then
    Else
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        aShe.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next aShe

Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = SheetName

Set DeleteAndAddSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

End Function

Sub Popluate_Ranges()

Dim WsS As Worksheet
Set WsS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim WsR As Worksheet
Set WsR = DeleteAndAddSheet("Results")
Dim sc As Integer
Dim sr As Integer
Dim rc As Integer
Dim rr As Long
Dim rr2 As Long
Dim rc2 As Integer
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim v1 As String
Dim v2 As String
Dim d As String
Dim e As String
Dim f As String
Dim i As Integer

'break string into 3 parts for handling

rr = 1
rc = 1
sr = 2
sc = 1

For sr = 2 To WsS.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

    For sc = 1 To 2
    'write the first digit to first result column
    WsR.Cells(rr, rc) = Left(Format(WsS.Cells(sr, sc), "00000"), 1)
    rc = rc + 1
    'write the middle 3 digits to the second result column
    WsR.Cells(rr, rc) = Right(Left(Format(WsS.Cells(sr, sc), "00000"), 4), 3)
    rc = rc + 1
    'write the last digit to the third result column
    WsR.Cells(rr, rc) = Right(Format(WsS.Cells(sr, sc), "00000"), 1)
    rc = rc + 1
    Next sc

    'write ccs
    WsR.Cells(rr, rc) = WsS.Cells(sr, sc)
    rr = rr + 1
    rc = 1

Next sr
WsR.Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "000"
WsR.Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "000"

rr = 1
rc = 1
rr2 = 1
rc2 = 8

For rr = 1 To WsR.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        'write/rejoin range start value

        a = WsR.Cells(rr, rc).Value
        b = WsR.Cells(rr, rc + 1).Value
        c = WsR.Cells(rr, rc + 2).Value
        WsR.Cells(rr2, rc2) = Format(a, "0") & Format(b, "000") & Format(c, "0")
        WsR.Cells(rr2, rc2 + 1) = WsR.Cells(rr, 7).Value
        rr2 = rr2 + 1

        'check if at the end of the range
        d = WsR.Cells(rr, rc + 3).Value
        e = WsR.Cells(rr, rc + 4).Value
        f = WsR.Cells(rr, rc + 5).Value


        Do Until (a = d And b = e And c = f)

                If IsNumeric(a) = False Then
                    i = a
                    i = i + 1
                    v1 = a
                    c = Right(i, 1)
                    v2 = a
                    If v1 = 9 And v2 = 0 Then
                        b = b + 1
                    End If

                ElseIf IsNumeric(c) = False Then

                    b = b + 1

                Else:
                i = c
                    i = i + 1
                    v1 = c
                    c = Right(i, 1)
                    v2 = c
                    If v1 = 9 And v2 = 0 Then
                        b = b + 1
                    End If

                End If

                WsR.Cells(rr2, rc2) = Format(a, "0") & Format(b, "000") & Format(c, "0")
                WsR.Cells(rr2, rc2 + 1) = WsR.Cells(rr, 7).Value
                'WsR.Cells(rr2, rc2 + 2) = rr
                rr2 = rr2 + 1

         Loop

Next rr
WsR.Range("H:H").NumberFormat = "00000"
WsR.Activate
Range("A1:G1").EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```